# Android FileInputStream read same data continuously

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer, fileinputstream

I want to make bluetooth socket communication sending files

I read data by buffer from FileInputStream, and write it on other output stream.

But this program read same data continuously, not read next content.

here is my source

```
        MSendArgWrapper wrapper = makeWrapper(sendArg, MSendArgWrapper.MODE_SWITCH_FILE);
        try {
            byte[] bytes = CUtility.serialize(wrapper);
            outStream.write(bytes);
            outStream.flush();
            File file = new File(filePath);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            do {
                int numread = fis.read(buf);
                if (numread <= 0)
                    break;
                if(LOG_I_ENABLE)
                    Log.i(TAG, "[CCommunicateThread] Sending File... [" + numread + "] => " + buf.toString());
                outStream.write(buf, 0, numread);
            } while (true);
            outStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            onDisconnected();
        }
```

This is the log

```
08-16 08:07:21.002  20001-21388/com.example.park.psyche I/CBluetoothManager﹕ [CCommunicateThread] Sending File... [1024] => [B@42b0ab48
08-16 08:07:21.002  20001-21388/com.example.park.psyche I/CBluetoothManager﹕ [CCommunicateThread] Sending File... [1024] => [B@42b0ab48
08-16 08:07:21.002  20001-21388/com.example.park.psyche I/CBluetoothManager﹕ [CCommunicateThread] Sending File... [1024] => [B@42b0ab48
08-16 08:07:21.002  20001-21388/com.example.park.psyche I/CBluetoothManager﹕ [CCommunicateThread] Sending File... [1024] => [B@42b0ab48
08-16 08:07:21.002  20001-21388/com.example.park.psyche I/CBluetoothManager﹕ [CCommunicateThread] Sending File... [1024] => [B@42b0ab48
08-16 08:07:21.002  20001-21388/com.example.park.psyche I/CBluetoothManager﹕ [CCommunicateThread] Sending File... [1024] => [B@42b0ab48
08-16 08:07:21.002  20001-21388/com.example.park.psyche I/CBluetoothManager﹕ [CCommunicateThread] Sending File... [1024] => [B@42b0ab48
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working but what you print is not what you think it is.

A byte array type `byte[]` is an Object type. If you use method `toString()` it will not convert bytes to String.

If you want to convert a `byte[]` to a String type use : `new String(my_byte_array)`

with :

```
Log.i(TAG, "[CCommunicateThread] Sending File... [" + numread + "] => " + new String(buf));
```

You'll get the right output

Comment: Oh... I was so stupid.. I have another problem, however. If I send 7mb file, it takes 7sec. How can I speed up bluetooth file transfer?

Comment: I doubt it comes from your file reading implementation. Bluetooth is slow and this problem is often encountered. If you want to check that it dont come from your reading implementation put your file in a variable and make some speed test. Also I dont know for bluetooth socket but if you have 7MB of data that you could optimize your buffer size or even your flush frequency as explained in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689871/java-file-download-hangs. It could make sense because Smarphone have much more memory/performance constraints than server

Comment: Thank you for your help, but there is no way to speed up bluetooth file transfer I think...