# File Download by flushing response OutputStream

Tags: java, servlets, download, outputstream, flush

I am trying to download 800 MB file from google drive in a streamed fashion. Like I fetch bytes from google drive & write to my response output stream & flush it. Here is the code for it

```
public void downloadFileAsStream(String accessToken, String fileId
            , HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        Credential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = service.files().get(fileId).setFields("name, size").execute();
        }  catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred while getting file from google drive", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        long fileSize = file.getSize();
        OutputStream ros = response.getOutputStream();
        for (long i = 0; i<= fileSize; i=i+10000000) {
            byte[] fileRangeBytes = getBytes(service, accessToken, fileId, i, directDownloadThreshold);
            ros.write(fileRangeBytes);
            ros.flush();
        }
        ros.close();
    }

private byte[] getBytes(Drive drive, String accessToken, String fileId, long position, long byteCount) throws Exception {
    byte[] receivedByteArray = null;
    String downloadUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?alt=media&access_token="
            + accessToken;
    try {
        com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest httpRequestGet = drive.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(downloadUrl));
        httpRequestGet.getHeaders().setRange("bytes=" + position + "-" + (position + byteCount - 1));
        com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse response = httpRequestGet.execute();
        InputStream is = response.getContent();
        receivedByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        response.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return receivedByteArray;
}
```

The problem here is that the files are not getting downloaded in the browser immediately in chunks

Rather my application just keeps waiting till the whole file is written to response's outputstream.

So why is the flushing to the browser not happening in my case though I have responseOutputStream.flush() inside the for loop like in this question [Java file download hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689871/java-file-download-hangs/25689980#25689980)

Comment: There is no chunking here. All you are doing is streaming bytes. If you want chunking, implement chunking.

Comment: @EJP My question is why is the bytes not directly streamed to response output stream i.e browser though I am flushing it often ?